# Reduce dimensionality in pandas.Panel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to remove unnecessary dimensions in pandas.Panel (by unnecessary I mean those which have only one value). I'm looking for a generic way to do it. I'm pretty new to Python and pandas library.

So, for example, a panel of shape: 3x1x4 should be converted into 3x4 DataFrame.

Do you know if something like this already exists?

Comment: [squeeze](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.Panel.squeeze.html#pandas.Panel.squeeze)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have:

```
data = np.random.randn(100, 1, 4)
pf = pd.Panel(data)
pf.shape

(100, 1, 4)
```

You can:

```
pf.squeeze().T.shape
```

to get:

```
(100, 4)
```

Comment: It seems like 'squeeze' function is changing the original order of the axes. Let's say: if the original shape of the panel is (2,1,273) after squeezing it will be (273,2) instead of (2,273). Do you know how to handle this one in a generic way?